# Launching help page in Help Viewer in 10.6

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I launch help file in 10.4 and 10.5 using AHGotoPage which work great.

When I try launching in 10.6 I get error "hVURLHandlerErrorDomain error 1003" but no idea why.

Note: The error is only on Release version not in Debug.

I even tried with AHLookupAnchor, even this gives the error. Am I missing some thing in solution? Is there any other solution I can try? is there any specific change in help file launching in 10.6?

thanks for all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replaced the call AHGotoPage to [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURLs: so that I can lauch help file which is working great.